Is there an implementation of the ATRPO algorithm that allows for Discrete Actions?
I'm working on a project with my teacher, and we intended to test the ATRPO (Average Reward TRPO) against different state of the art algorithms. However, I only managed to find one library that uses it (https://github.com/sony/nnabla-rl), and sadly it's implemented in a way where it does not support Discrete Actions, which means we couldn't use the intended environment.
Is there perhaps an alternative implementation of this code that could work for that? I really couldn't find anything of the sort, and lack the experience to try and code it completely by myself, so I thought I'd ask here. I just need something I could use for environments with discrete actions, even if it's not within a library.
Thanks in advance!
